# My hosting server firewall always blocks my joomla site when in login to admin panel

Tags: php, joomla, ip, hosting, block

Whenever i login to my any joomla site admin backend on my hosting server, my ip get blocked by the server firewall, asking about it the hosting ticket replies, They only allow 200 connections at a time for 1 website. their CSF firewall is blocking my site ip.

it only happens when i try to login to my joomla admin backend. how can i limit my joomla connections to server.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your .htaccess file of root directory based on [here](http://www.ashesh.com.np/beginners-guide-to-htaccess-file-with-examples-%E2%80%93part-ii/) :

Syntax:
MaxClients < number-of-connections>

Examples:
MaxClients 40
MaxClients 100

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: got it, but when i put it, it says INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.